# How to access GET method from another controller in asp.net core mvc?

Tags: asp.net-core, controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two controllers: OcorrenciasAPI and IgnicoesAPI . I need to access the GET method in my controller IgnicoesAPI trough OcorrenciasAPI controller. What's the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact answer to your question, but this may solve your problem. Refractor your code inside the GET method into a common class and access this class from both controller. Adding sample code below.

Model

```
public sealed class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Repository

```
public class PersonRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        return new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person{ID = 1, Name = "Name 1" },
            new Person{ID = 2, Name = "Name 2" }
        };
    }
}
```

First Api Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MyFirstApiController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly PersonRepository personRepository = new PersonRepository();

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Models.Person> Get()
    {
        return personRepository.GetPeople();
    }
}
```

Second Api Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MySecoundApiController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly PersonRepository personRepository = new PersonRepository();
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        // Calling same repository here.
        var people = personRepository.GetPeople();

        return people.Select(p=> p.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would appreciate if you shared a demo code, please

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class with the shared functionality, add it as a service in your startup.cs and then inject it into your controllers.

```
public interface IMyService
{
    string MyMethod();
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public string MyMethod()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

*Startup.cs*

```
services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();
```

*OcorrenciasAPI constructor*

```
  private readonly IMyService _myService;

    public OcorrenciasAPI (IMyService  myService)
    {
       _myService = myService
    }
```

*IgnicoesAPI constructor*

```
  private readonly IMyService _myService;

    public IgnicoesAPI(IMyService  myService)
    {
       _myService = myService
    }
```

*Use*

```
var result = _myService.MyMethod();
```