# How to find internally calling service URLs from first service in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, fiddler, wcftestclient

I would like to know how to find the urls of internally referred services when hitting the first service.. is there any way? in fiddler I couldn't find.
I have a webservice customer.asmx contains method A(). I know only customer.asmx service complete url, with it's URL I am testing the method A in wcftestclient.
I get to know through code method A is calling reports.asmx and again resports.asmx is calling another service catalogue.asmx.
I am actually testing the test environment service, so I am not sure of the reports.asmx to which it is pointing I want to find out

Is there any way to know the complete urls of reports and catalogue services while testing my initial customer.asmx.

Comment: similar question here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63471252/how-to-access-get-method-from-another-controller-in-asp-net-core-mvc/63471335#63471335

Comment: not actually. I just have first url in my hand, by testing it's method A I need to find out other two service complete urls which it is first service hitting.  testing also I can done using soap ui /wcftestclient. only. using fiddler I am checking

Comment: Fiddler will only tell you about the traffic from your browser to your service url endpoint.  It won't tell you anything else.

Comment: so with my first service customer.asmx, is it not possible to find out other two which it is hitting internally? any other option

Comment: Look at the code?

Comment: no code access currently for me and also no access to servers. so we can't find out internal service urls...is what you mean?

Comment: We cannot know the URI of the internal call service.